# Atom - Unable to save file: Permission denied (Windows)

Tags: powershell, atom-editor, permission-denied

I've been a long time user of *notepad++* and I enjoy it a lot, but a friend recently recommended me to use Atom, so I gave it a try. However, when I try to save *anything* in my project folder (or any file at all), I receive this message that I am `unable to save file: permission denied`.

[image]

I've tried typing the command `sudo atom /path/to/file` in my *PowerShell* for Windows, but I get the following message:

[image]

I understand that `sudo` is a Linux-based command and thus would not work in a Windows environment but would there be an alternative route to get Atom working on my machine?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you run the app as administrator ?

Comment: Hi ArcSet! Yes, I did try running Atom on administrator but no go. It works perfectly on notepad++, but can't save at all on Atom

Answer (score 2):

The files were made "Read Only" somehow (maybe your anti-virus software or something, who knows...).

Solution:
Go to the folder in the Explorer, highlight all of the files in your project.  Right click, open the properties.  Deselect "Read-Only" and push ok.  When it asks if you would like to apply to only the selected files or also to the files in any sub-folders, click yes if you need to.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your reply. i recently installed Atom again after months of not using it and it worked again with no problems. i'll be certain to use this solution if Atom doesn't save files again. thanks a lot Paul!

Comment: This fix just saved me a lot of heartache. Worked perfectly.